# What is the result of extremely over-fermenting bread dough?

Tags: dough, fermentation, mistakes

I left some dough to ferment in a 2L container in the fridge, got distracted by a hospitalization, and didn't remember it again until 6 weeks later.

The lid hadn't popped open and the dough looked and smelled fine, but the texture was very strange, wet, gooey, and not like anything I'd seen before.

I cooked a small amount and the result was nothing like bread, but more soft and rubbery, with a texture somewhat like jelly or Turkish delight (but not sweet or flavoured).

**What is this interesting substance, does it have a name, and is there anything for which it can be used as an ingredient?**

(I'm not worried about wasting it and throwing it away; I jut think it looks like it should be useful for making something I've never tried before.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Most likely you have created a sourdough starter, which is a microbial colony containing yeast (make it rise), and Lactobacterii (produce lactic acid, make it sour), and other microbes that give it a unique flavor.

But why is the cooked dough soft and rubbery and not bread like? Lactobacterii digest gluten, and have has had 6 weeks to turn all of the wheat gluten into food. Which is why the dough is now soup like (that and the yeast digesting all of the carbs). And gluten as a protein, is what gives your bread structure, no gluten = no structure. The rubbery bit probably comes from undigested bits of gluten and other carbohydrates.

What can I do with it? Try adding some flour/water and see if it is indeed alive (I've had sourdough come back after being forgotten for 7 months in a refrigerator.. I've also had sourdough that died after being forgotten for 3 weeks). If it is alive, and you like how the bread it makes tastes. Congratulations! You have created a sourdough starter on accident.

---

Note the more traditional way to create a sourdough starter is to use a mix of equal parts whole wheat flour and water, and then wait somewhere between 2 days and 3 weeks with the starter at room temperature, with fingers crossed that it will start bubbling, instead of growing mold (though after 2 weeks, it's better to repeat the attempt... don't want a slow growing yeast).

---

There was some excessive concern about food safety in a heavily downvoted answer, but for future refence this is how you tell if food is bad:

1. Smell, does it smell bad? If so throw it away. The human nose is remarkably good at detecting a wide range of toxic substances.
2. Appearance, does it have mold (green, or black specks) growing on/in it? If so, throw it out.
3. Does it have a live culture (such as being a sourdough starter/ wet yeast). As long as the sourdough starter is 'alive' the yeast/lactic bacteria will prevent other microbes from colonizing it. It should be fine. (this is why raw milk goes sour and is still edible for a time... while pasteurized milk goes rancid and is inedible).

The bacteria that you have to worry about with bread:

- E. Coli bacterium, A bacterial infection is not a concern as it dies at 160 F. A specific variant can produce E. Coli Shiga... produces Shiga toxin which is inactivated at 212 F after 5 minutes which might be a concern as most bread is considered 'done' when the middle reaches somewhere between 190F and 210. But I wouldn't be to concerned over it as E. Coli produces an unpleasant sulfurous odor, which is noticeable
- Salmonella dies between 145 and 160 F. If you cooked the bread, not a problem.

Everything else, highly unlikely.

- Clostridium botulinum is an anaerobic bacterium, unless your bread dough was in a low oxygen environment (such as a sealed can) it's fine.

Finally as with everything in life:

- Trust your common sense. If there is something that looks off about the food. Throw it. Its better to be safe then sorry*

*<sub>That being said, we wouldn't have bread, cheese, butter, wine, beer, lutefisk, vegemite, mead, soy sauce, fish sauce, ketchup, raisins, beef jerky, cooked meat, etc.. If someone hadn't ignored their instincts that said "don't try anything that looks weird"</sub>

Comment: I appreciate the effort to answer the general food safety question, but you're probably better off focusing on bread dough specifically. Killing bacteria doesn't make food safe; sourdough is safe because the culture prevents harmful bacteria from ever multiplying enough to produce enough toxins to cause issues.

Comment: It's definitely still alive. I took 100g of the stuff, added 200g of new flour, salt, and water (80%) and despite its being too wet and requiring 45 minutes to bake, it turned out better than I expected: [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlqGA.jpg).

Comment: While I know you're including extraneous details on food poisoning just to be extra precautions. I do wonder if the internal temperature of the bread ever actually reaches or exceeds 350F. The crumb still has water in it which might keep the internal temp from rising that high. I know that much of that is converted to steam, but water in a liquid state cannot usually exceed 212F. An article by Taste of Home's test kitchen claims an internal temp of 185F for their bread recipe, so it may vary depending on the bread you're making, but I don't believe most breads will reach 350 internal temp

Comment: That said, I don't think it will be a problem. Humans have been making sour dough for thousands of years. Bakeries do this, and it doesn't seem like it's ever been a major food safety concern. I just wanted to point out that if, for whatever unlikely reason, you're bread is contaminated with botulism, baking if is might not going to get the internal temperature of most breads high enough. I'm really splitting hairs here, and think the detail in your answer is otherwise very good.

Comment: @tsturzl That is a good point. I hadn't thought to check the internal... I personally am not concerned about botulism as it is an anaerobic bacteria that is extremely unlikely to grow in the aerobic conditions found in bread dough. ..

Answer (score 35):

It has a name: sourdough.

This may surprise you if you are accustomed to thinking of sourdough as something created through an arcane process of feeding, discarding, coddling at special temperatures or improving with fruit juices. All that stuff is simply the side effect of the way modern food geeks approach their hobby, and a workable way of producing one specific type of sourdough. But it's not what makes sourdough a sourdough. A sourdough is any dough which has been left to ferment for a very long time, creating a stable microbial colony with a distinct taste.

A sourdough can be baked directly, like you did, although that's rarely done. The more common role is to use it as a preferment and add it to freshly made bread dough, alone or with other leaveners. There are also recipes for other baked goods, such as waffles, which use sourdough. Look around for recipes including sourdough, and you'll find a lot.

If you enjoy the taste of the particular colony you created, and don't want to use it up, you can replenish your sourdough with more flour and water any time you take away some for baking.

Comment: I suspect it will change a fair bit over a few cycles of using and feeding - but it will still be sourdough and quite possibly very good sourdough. It tends to adapt to its environment and feeding cycle (availability of nutrients for the various species in there) and this presumably started out heavy on commercial yeast

Comment: "very strange, wet, gooey, and not like anything I'd seen before" is why sour doughs are used as a pre-ferment.

Comment: Possibly not a sourdough as we would expect it per se, but the technique of keeping some (yeasted) dough as starter is also very old, although slightly forgotten thanks to easy access to commercial yeast. (And experimentally proven during the Covid food shortage craze, when I had to stretch my one measly cake of yeast as much as possible.) Over time, the “old dough” will likely become a more classic sourdough when the biome changes through continuous feeding.

Comment: Likely a pretty normal sourdough, though one that's gone that long without feeding will indeed have gobbled up the gluten and be rather "odd" until it's fed and brought back to a happy-bread-making state.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It might taste a bit too sour/be a slow riser for a while because of the imbalance between yeast and lactobacteria. I would recommend going thru a couple of feed cycles before using it to shift the balance towards yeast a bit more.

Comment: That being what the part of the comment after "until" is about...

Comment: @rutscho I would mention that the result being soft/rubbery is caused because all of the gluten in the dough has been digested by lactobacteri.

Answer (score -14):

Bro, you left the bread dough for 6 WEEKS? After as little as 10 days it already starts to become substandard quality and it's even hard to imagine how it is after 6 weeks. Nonethtless, it is certainly something no animal should consume, much less a human. This "interesting substance" has a name, it's called rancid and spoiled food, and it should only ever be used as an ingredient in making up the composition of garbage bin's contents. Stay safe and better start over, good luck.

Comment: There exists a highly upvoted and educated answer...and then there's this answer

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I cannot in good conscience advise anybody to consume something that is most probably going to cause serious food poisoning. Since you apparently have nothing constructive to say, I'd advise you to go pick fights with your passive-aggressive snark somewhere else.

Comment: @HumanofPeople his snark is because OP created a yeast colony, and an early answer is well educated and thought out... Though calling it sourdough is a bit of a stretch it possible it might not be sour.  While it might have an unpleasant flavor (not all 'sourdough' tastes good), it certainly isn't rancid or spoiled. It should be safe for consumption, as long as it doesn't smell bad. The container was not sealed so there isn't  a danger of Botulism as that requires anaerobic conditions.

Comment: The question isn't asking if anyone should eat it, it's just asking what it is. Yes, food left in incorrect storage conditions generally becomes completely inedible and dangerous, but sometimes it doesn't - what is cheese but properly spoiled milk? So I think the question is okay. OP was ill-advised to try eating some of it.

Comment: The asker reports no visible spoilage and no off scent or flavor. As they didn’t start with a random food item, but with a dough intended and thus composed for fermentation. The result, as so diligently explained in the other answer, is simply the consequent process over a longer time. This process of propagating works with a classic sourdough, but yeast-based doughs will work as well. There is a risk of spoilage, but unlike for other foods, the probably heavy presence of yeast from the start gave it a good head start to outcompete pathogens and spoilage would be evident.

Comment: To the answerer, I'm not sure you're understanding how (over)dramatic your answer and subsequent comments read. At least to me ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯, possibly others.

Comment: @user253751 Cheese being "properly spoiled milk" doesn't make cheese immune to spoilage. It is the same with dough. The only food items that can remain edible forever are honey and salt, all else spoils sooner or later. 6 weeks for a bread dough is DEFINITELY too much. Of course it is not guaranteed that consuming that old dough is going to result in food poisoning, but after 6 weeks it is guaranteed that it is going to taste horrible and have repulsively unpleasant texture, so why even entertain the idea of using it for anything in the kitchen? Just throw it away and start over.

Comment: @Questor As much as people are brownnosing the other answer, it doesn't cite any references either, and the author is not going to suffer the consequences if the question's author get food poisoning. Six weeks is way too sketchy for me, and no other person mentions the possibility of food poisoning, so there should at least be a common-sense warning.

Comment: @Questor OP created a yeast colony, correct, but the amount of carbohydrates in the box is finite and once the yeast run out of food, they will start dying and decaying, creating a nutritious soup with all their juicy cell contents spilling out for airborne pathogens to settle and thrive in and then nobody could predict what types of different toxins could start to appear.

Comment: @HumanofPeople Not very likely, lactobacillaceae are the culprit for the soupy mess (they eat gluten) and produce lactid acid which lowers the PH of the growth medium (flour). If you get a colony sitting in the refrigerator for that long, the PH is should be enough that most other pathogens are prevented from growing. Source? I, and thousands of other bakers have done this exact thing on purpose trying to grow our own sourdough starter, not 6 weeks on purpose. And it doesn't work every time, but it is extremely obvious when it has failed as there is mold and/or a foul odor.

Comment: This answer is beyond ignorant. My sourdough starter has been living in the fridge for more than 6 years now...and has been utterly fine on various occasions when it went more than 6 weeks without being used.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use the flour mixture for bread as it will be extremely sour, almost inedible at this point. And have no structure because there is no longer any gluten. But it works perfectly fine as a starter.

Comment: @Ecnerwal So you have got nothing more than a personal anecdote? How you could guarantee that it will be safe every time? It is you who is beyond ignorant.

Comment: @Questor If you use it as nothing more than a starter, then I guess it's fair enough if you don't use too much, but at that point why voluntarily use an old and rancid starter that could introduce off-flavors? I'd say it's better to just start over and use a fresher one.

Comment: A few thousand years of practical experience (plenty of research as well, in the past couple of hundred years once microscopes got themselves invented) are as nothing against your baseless assertion...only in *your* mind.

Comment: @Stephie I agree, however, the answers are not just for the person asking the question, but also for all the readers from the Internet. OP doesn't mention spoilage and bad odors, correct, but one cannot guarantee the same for all the potential readers who might have the same problem. Those readers should have a chance to see some sort of warning, just because OP's dough may be okay doesn't make it safe in 100% cases. Cheers.

Comment: @HumanofPeople That you apparently didn't know what a sourdough starter was/how one could create a sourdough starter at the start of this thread should tell you something about your level of knowledge compared to the people you are talking down to.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Food spoilage is a thing, as well as food poisoning. Your rambling about "microscopes" and "thousands of years" doesn't make those non-factors.

Comment: @HumanofPeople nevertheless *your answer should fit the question* - and claiming that what they described as “the dough looked and smelled fine” instead is “rancid and spoiled food” may be based on good intentions, but is likely incorrect, as the downvotes suggest. Your tone in the answer doesn’t help either.

Comment: @Questor I know what a dough starter is and I have experienced smelling old and rancid ones. I wonder if you continued that preachy and scolding attitude like that if you were legally liable for potential food poisonings of this Q&A's readers.

Comment: All right, I think it's time to step back from the commenting. Plenty of people have given feedback about this answer - including the fact that it doesn't seem to be describing the same situation as described in the question - and the author is free to take it or leave it.